# Laravel unstaliling tymon/jwt-auth package throws class LaravelServiceProvider not found

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, tymon-jwt

I'm trying to uninstall [jwt-auth](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth) from my Laravel 8 application. I've removed all references to `Tymon\JWTAuth`, have done a composer clear-cache, my config no longer exists, it's been removed from the app config, but still, laravel throws the error, what am I missing:

```
In ProviderRepository.php line 208:
                                                                    
  Class 'Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LaravelServiceProvider' not found
```

Comment: Could you please share you composer.json file

Answer (score -1):

Check your `config/app.php` file you must have used `Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LaravelServiceProvider` in providers array

```php
'providers' => [

        /*
         * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
         */
       ...
       Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\LaravelServiceProvider::class
       ...
]
```

Comment: if you still face issues, i'll recommend remove the vendors folder and do a fresh `composer install`

Comment: @Akszar, It's mentioned that, it's been removed from the app config so how above one will work.